# How to get the oldest file in a directory using C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm implementing log mechanism and I want to delete oldest log file based on time creating in the directory when reach the defined size.

But now I stuck on getting the oldest file based on time creating.
How to get it using C?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Getting the files in the directory, getting their ages, sorting, deleting a file?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I stuck on getting the oldest file based on time creating

Comment: Create a `struct` holding the filename and the modification time. Create an array of them. Read your directory copying the name and mod time to elements within your array of struct. (after closing the directory) `qsort` your array by the time member and then `unlink` the `array[0].filename` to delete the oldest file.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `logrotate`?

Comment: Why do it by time instead of giving files a numeric suffix and using that?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You're out of luck.  Directories don't store file create times.

Comment: @Barmar: I'd assume that `logrotate` is a crippled joke that should never have existed - e.g. if it rotates logs daily, but you have a problem (e.g. DDoS attack) that causes your log to fill the entire disk in 10 minutes then ...).

Comment: See [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)

Comment: @Brendan You can specify that log files are rotated on a fixed schedule or when they grow larger than a specified size. It's common to run it daily, but you can increase the frequency if you want. The same problem exists with a DIY solution, doesn't it?

Comment: @Barmar: For a DIY solution the rules are whatever you want them to be - e.g. maybe "`create new log file if the next "atomic append" would have made the current log file larger than X bytes; or when the current log file is older than Y; or when an admin logs in and changes settings.`". You can also do custom compaction if you want (e.g. open logs from the oldest week, strip out less important info; then merge the remaining more important info into a single weekly file). Mostly, it's "less flexible external tool that was probably misconfigured" vs. "do it right".

Comment: @Brendan Most of that is possible with `logrotate`. You can configure a script to run to process the file after rotation. It's very flexible.

Comment: @Barmar: Sounds great if you want "installation" to be 1000 error prone steps with 50 dependencies scattered everywhere.

Comment: @Brendan Sounds like you're arguing against all general-purpose tools.

Comment: @Brendan What "doesn't work"? `logrotate` is a framework for log rotation that allows flexible configuration and customization? We use it to trigger our script that collects statistics from our web access log at the same time as it's rotating, it works fine.

Comment: @Brendan Do you have the same problem with `systemd`, too?

Comment: @Barmar: Web development is like a rolling cluster-bork of incompetence where it makes no difference how poorly designed your product is because its running on your server where no end users see it. This question is tagged `C`. Imagine an end user installing a single process written in pure C, and compare that to an end user installing your HTML/CSS files and then having to figure out the rest of your "web server + logrotate + script + who knows what else" (that you've probably spent months trying to get to work) all by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a portable way to get a file's creation time (or its modification time) in C.

Instead you need to rely on something that isn't strictly portable - e.g. use the file name from the directory entry with the `stat()` function defined by POSIX, to get a structure that might or might not have a `struct timespec st_ctim;` field.

Of course some file systems don't have a creation time at all; and even if there is one if you copy a file elsewhere (e.g. to remote storage) the creation time will be gone, so it's relatively unreliable.

Instead; it's much better to put the creation time and date into the file name. If you do this in the correct order ("year, month, day, hour, minute, second" - e.g. maybe like "`mylog_2019-10-31_14-23-45.txt`") and keep leading zeros (e.g. `09` for month and never `9` for month) then sorting a list of file names alphanumerically will also sort them chronologically.

Comment: The question is tagged `linux`, so a portable solution probably isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

you should maintain an internal queue of file name. New one created is added to the head constantly. When need delete , let delete the tail guy